# PositionSensor Resolution Unit Definition?

Tags: webots

The position sensor's resolution field simply has a float value, but not even the documentation of the position sensor specifies what unit is used, does anyone know ? (or can we just infer that it is rad/s as the motor's position is in that unit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have unit because it depends on the type of joint it is attached to.

For hinge-joints, hinge-2-joints and ball-joints the units are radians and for slider-joints the units are meters.